# Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class ’XYX’ with RestKit-0.20.3

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am working with RestKit-0.20.3 and faced a problem
I have a Student table in database. For getting student history perform get api call, url like this https://xyz.com/api/getStudentHistory?x=a&y=b&z=c with some parameter.
Using this method

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:param success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
```

In '**path'** parameter passing- path = https://xyz.com/api/getStudentHistory

I got this error when server send response.

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class ’Student’
```

After that I am getting this message and application become crash.

```
Uncaught exception [<Student 0xd36b3e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "notes".
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Student 0xd36b3e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "notes".'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "title"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268580/the-entity-null-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-title)

Comment: The combination of base URL and path pattern need to create a valid URL in all cases and path pattern alone is used to match descriptors.

Comment: Yes @Wain you are right, I got clue from there I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

After R&D and spending a lot of time got a clue from here
[The entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "title"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268580/the-entity-null-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-title)

Simply replace my path parameter from path = https://xyz.com/api/getStudentHistory to path = /api/getStudentHistory
in method

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:param success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
```

Now my problem solved……:)